# Better way of pushing a list into a new activity?

Tags: java, android, android-activity

So as the title says, my app refuses to enter the new activity and its most likely related to a list intent i put into the code. I added some code that will push a list full of data, and the data is related to a specific URL so the data inside the list will differ with different items and there associated URLs, to a another activity, and the data will be read from the URL and be used. There is another thing that may be the cause of this problem and that is this warning related to this code.

WARNING: `Unchecked cast: 'java.io.Serializable' to 'java.util.List<com.example.drip.Classes.Chapter>'`

Code: `list = (List<Chapter>) intent.getSerializableExtra("LIST");` and the code in my adapter so that when the item gets clicked, `intent.putExtra("LIST",(Serializable) Data);` it uses that to push to the next activity.

Nevertheless, when I uncomment that code and anything that uses that code, which are just functions that loop through it to find something, the program works fine but when it comes to URL with heavy data like 600 entries then it doesn't work. So my question is that is there a limit to how much data you can pass through this method or is it really the warning that is prohibiting me from continuing to the new activity. BTW, I don't get any errors.

Comment: convert the list into String using Gson and pass it to new activity... after receiving the String on 2nd activity, convert it to List using Gson

Comment: so was my guess right? the array is to big to pass through activities?

Comment: yes, most likely

Comment: coolio, thanks for the solution